# Listar todos os triggers no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Existe algum comando, que liste todas as *triggers* de um banco no SQL Server?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/ListTriggers.sql).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms188746(v=sql.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 3):

Seria isso que você está procurando?

```
SELECT Object_Name(parent_id) AS [Nome Objeto], 
       type_desc              AS Tipo, 
       modify_date            AS [Data Modificação] 
FROM   sys.triggers
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o select abaixo.

```
SELECT 
     sysobjects.name AS trigger_name 
    ,USER_NAME(sysobjects.uid) AS trigger_owner 
    ,s.name AS table_schema 
    ,OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) AS table_name 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger') AS isupdate 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger') AS isdelete 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsertTrigger') AS isinsert 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsAfterTrigger') AS isafter 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsteadOfTrigger') AS isinsteadof 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled') AS [disabled] 
FROM sysobjects 
INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON sysobjects.parent_obj = t.object_id     
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE sysobjects.type = 'TR'
```

Ele retorna além do nome da trigger a tabela que a usar.

[Documentação com select do objeto trigger.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179309.aspx)